# Convert series to other format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with a column `"Name"`, which is a series of values like:

```
0    Brian
1    Natasha
2    Mike
3    Anthony
4    Steve
```

I want to convert this in below format:

```
["Brian","Natasha","Mike","Anthony","Steve"]
```

How do I perform this task using pandas?

Comment: `df.Name.tolist()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Series have a `tolist` method.

```
df["Name"].tolist()
```